# Is there a way to use command line for load testing a web URL (single web page) using jmeter without creating test plan

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to use command line for load testing a web URL (single web page) using jmeter without creating test plan file. (i.e. *.jmx)

Thanks,
Yugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called Apache Benchmark tool.

Comment: Thanks Andrey Pohilko,
So it means there is no need of using Jmeter tool in that case.